# Не выводится первая запись из БД PHP

Tags: php, mysql, while

Вывожу все записи из таблицы MySQL с помощью цикла while. Если делаю так, выводит все записи:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `property`";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Если вот так, одну запись (первую) не выводит:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `property`";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему?

Comment: *почему?* Потому что первая запись уже выбрана до начала цикла.

Comment: Оказывается, это так работает)) спасибо большое:)

Comment: ??? а как оно могло ещё работать? `mysql_fetch_assoc` - выгребает очередную запись / смещает указатель на следующую. И пофиг, где она - в цикле или перед ним. Не нравится - есть `mysql_data_seek`, которая может  вернуть указатель на первую запись набора перед началом цикла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вызов смещает указатель на следующую запись

```
$user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

While уже работает со второй строки

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

Нужно удалить строку

```
$user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```